# How to implement OpenID authentication for my site?

Tags: openid, authentication

I want to offer OpenID authentication for my users (please note that I do not necessary want to become an OpenID provider; I just need to authenticate my user for my website).

How to implement OpenID authentication for my site?

What are the requirements?

Comment: This belongs on StackOverflow because it's a programming question.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about what "your site" means? If it's built with some particular CMS/framework or even language, that'd narrow down the possibilities significantly.

Comment: I was thinking about JSP, but Si Philp' answer cover practically anything, so there's no need to specify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out the following page. Gives a run down on the open id libraries out and about depending on your platform.

http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries